# Swift lazy cartesian product

Tags: swift, iterator, lazy-evaluation

I have this function in swift

```
func *<T1:Sequence, T2:Sequence>(lhs: T1,rhs : T2) ->
              [(T1.Iterator.Element,T2.Iterator.Element)] 
{
    let product = lhs.flatMap({ x in rhs.lazy.map{y in (x,y)}})
    return product
}
```

I want to make it evaluate lazy. I know i can use lhs.lazy.flatmap but what should the return type be? Or is there a better or other way to do something like this?

Comment: Option click `flatMap` in `lhs.lazy.flatMap` and all will be revealed. Or just `print(type(of: lhs.flatMap({ x in rhs.lazy.map{y in (x,y)}})))`

Comment: Thanks very much. I get   LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<CountableClosedRange<Int>, LazyMapSequence<CountableClosedRange<Int>, (Int, Int)>>>> . I tried it with Int as you van see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a [*type-erased sequence*](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anysequence), which forward its operations to an underlying base
sequence having the same `Element` type, hiding the specifics of the
underlying sequence:

```
func *<T1:Sequence, T2:Sequence>(lhs: T1,rhs : T2) -> AnySequence<(T1.Iterator.Element,T2.Iterator.Element)> 
{
    return AnySequence (
        lhs.lazy.flatMap { x in rhs.lazy.map { y in (x,y) }}
    )
}
```

Then your code is independent of the actual implementation of `lazy.flatMap` and its exact return type (which may even change with
newer Swift releases).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alexander I came up with

```
func *<T1:Sequence, T2:Sequence>(lhs: T1,rhs : T2) ->     
          LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<T1,
          LazyMapSequence<T2, (T1.Iterator.Element, T2.Iterator.Element)>>>> {
    let product =  lhs.lazy.flatMap({ x in rhs.lazy.map{y in (x,y)}})
    print(type(of:product))
    return product
}
```

That works but somehow that return type seems a bit to much for my taste.